# PhoneRTC ionic Crashing on establishing call (ANDROID)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonertc

This the flow till now.
Send call from mobile A to B, 
Accept the call from B (initiating session with isInitiator false as per documents for mobile B), then the signal goes to mobile A for the event "answer" and I try to create a session on Mobile A with isInitiator=true. 
Everything works ok but when I can call session.call() on mobile A, it crashes.

What Am I Missing?

```
var config = {
      isInitiator: isInitiator,
      stun: {
        host: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
      },
      turn: {
        host: 'turn:numb.viagenie.ca',
        username: 'webrtc@live.com',
        password: 'muazkh'
      },
      streams: {
        audio: true,
        video: false
      }
    };
```